# Grammar of stellar classification

Tags: star, classification, stellar-classification

How to write G2V correctly (I mean space)? I saw in articles $ G\,2\,V$ and  $G2\,V$, on the internet webside it is usually $ G2V$.

Comment: [No space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification).

Comment: Is WIKI reliable source?  in A&A are small space: [article (Introduction for instance)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/44844166_Physical_elements_of_the_eclipsing_binary_delta_Orionis)

Answer (score 4):

One reason to prefer the space between the temperature and luminosity classes is that the hypergiant luminosity class is "0", which could be confused with a subtype. Usually this appears as part of a range with luminosity class "Ia" as opposed to on its own, but this range is often written as "0-Ia". Something like "G5 0-Ia" is more comprehensible than "G50-Ia".

If you're writing a parser, be prepared to handle both. In general, parsing spectral types is a bit tricky (I have written spectral type parsers before, it's "fun") and there are a surprising number of annoying edge cases. It would be nice if astronomical catalogues also included something like the [IVOA spectral type encoding](http://www.ivoa.net/documents/latest/SpectClasses.html), but usually the furthest you get is some bespoke system that only encodes standard OBAFGKM types and provides no way to encode, say, carbon stars or Wolf-Rayet types, even though the catalogue contains examples of these.

Some other issues you may run into:

- The ambiguity between "-" as a minus sign and "-" as a range symbol. Uusually the machine-readable files will be ASCII so none of the other dashes in Unicode are available, and given the general state of things I wouldn't trust them to be used reliably anyway!
- The previously-mentioned "0-Ia" luminosity class range means that a parser will run into an ambiguous interpretation of "G0-Ia": either an open ended range "G0 or earlier" of luminosity class "Ia", or a "G" type star with no subtype and luminosity class range "0-Ia".
- The fact that "+" may be an open-ended range symbol or a multi-spectrum separator "M5+" (star of type M5 or later) vs "M5+..." and "M5+K2" (M5 star with companion).
- The peculiar A-type stars, e.g. "kA5hF0mA5 V".
- The various two-parameter systems for carbon and S-type stars.
- The fact that the entire spectral type or various subcomponents may be bracketed to indicate uncertainties...
- ...which must be distinguished from the use of square brackets to indicate that the star is the central star of a planetary nebula
- If you're really lucky, your source will render the spectral types in ALL UPPERCASE (so that peculiar A-star spectrum from a few bullet points up becomes "KA5HF0MA5") because it's been compiled using some Fortran code that hasn't been updated since the 1960s or something...

Comment: I thought we usually write hypergiants as Ia+ rather than 0.

Comment: @fasterthanlight - yes, but 0 can and has been used, so if you're processing spectral types from catalogues you are going to run into it at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would write G2V (with no spaces), as separating each part of the classification would cause some ambiguity. Basically, any star's classification would be written as 'Temperature class'+'Digit'+'Star type.'